# Pyautogui change search area

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, pyautogui

In pyautogui, i'm working on a piano tiles bot. Is there any way to either only look for an image in a certain area, or click on all instances of that image?

Example:

```
import pyautogui

time.sleep(5):
pyautogui.click("Tile.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but for those who are still wondering, you can use `locateCenterOnScreen(picture, confidence, region=(left, top, width, height))` to find matches on a specified region. (parameter region is optional, you can also use the function without it.)

```
center = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("pic_to_find.png", confidence = 0.8)
pyautogui.click(center.x, center.y)
```

If the picture won't be located, you'll get `None` in return. So you could do something like

```
while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("Tile.png", confidence = 0.8) != None:
    click on it
```